# Dynamically allocating array, high level language to assembly MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

I need to convert C high level language into assembly language for MIPS. I'm stumped on this one. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

`array = new int [10] // dynamically allocating size`

What confuses me is the 'new int' portion, looking over my book and I can't find anything on it.

Comment: `new` usually allocates on the "heap" but, depending on the use, you may allocate the array on the stack instead. In the system you are programming on is there a system call to allocate memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's C++ or C#, not C.

If you're using MARS or SPIM, there is a system call for `sbrk`, which you can use to implement a heap allocator.  http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/syscallhelp.html.  If you don't care about freeing the memory later, simply use it directly: `syscall` with `$v0=9` allocates `$a0` more bytes of heap space, and returns the pointer in `$v0`.

---

**But often you can just reserve some stack space instead, if it's ok to deallocate it at the end of the function as part of tearing down this function's stack frame.**

In some high-level languages other than C++, there's no equivalent to `alloca` or `int array[10]` to make a local array with storage scoped only to the function, so even private scratch arrays have to use the same syntax as full-on dynamic allocation of long-lived objects.

A compiler for such languages does [escape analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_analysis) to figure out whether a reference to this storage could survive past the end of the function.  If not, the storage can be allocated on the stack.  (But if it does escape, it has to be allocated on the heap, e.g. with `malloc` or `mmap`.)

When "compiling" to asm by hand, you should do the escape analysis yourself.  If you don't return a pointer to the storage, and you don't pass its address to any function that holds onto it, then it's just scratch space that you can and should reserve stack space for, instead of calling the allocate and free system calls.

**On MIPS, this is what gcc5.4 does for a simple function ([source+asm on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'void+foo(void)+%7B%0A++++volatile+int+scratch%5B10%5D%3B%0A++++scratch%5B1%5D+%3D+0%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:51.99203187250996,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:mips5,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-fno-delayed-branch',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'MIPS+gcc+5.4+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:48.007968127490045,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+MIPS+gcc+5.4',t:'0')),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:48.007968127490045,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',m:100,n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)):**

```
void foo(void) {
    volatile int scratch[10];  // volatile so it can't optimize away
    scratch[1] = 0;
}
```

```
# gcc -O3 -fno-delayed-branch
foo():
        addiu   $sp,$sp,-48   # allocate space
        sw      $0,12($sp)    # store into it from the zero-register
        addiu   $sp,$sp,48    # restore stack pointer
        j       $31           # return
        nop                   # branch-delay slot filled with a NOP
```

So gcc decided that scratch would start at `$sp + 8`, so one 4-byte element after the first is at `$sp + 12`.